# Asp.net Vbscript Error

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

Please tell me where I have gone wrong in this script. I am getting this error.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'ProcessStartInfo' is not defined.

Source Error:

```
Line 5:  Public Shared Function ExecuteCommand(Command As String, Timeout As Integer) As Integer
Line 6:  Dim ExitCode As Integer
*Line 7:  Dim ProcessInfo As ProcessStartInfo*
Line 8:  Dim Process As Process
Line 9:
```

Source File: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ServiceFileUploadRE.aspx    Line: 7

**The Script:**

```
  <%@ Page Language=VBScript %>

    <script runat="server">

    Public Shared Function ExecuteCommand(Command As String, Timeout As Integer) As Integer
    Dim ExitCode As Integer
    Dim ProcessInfo As ProcessStartInfo
    Dim Process As Process

    ProcessInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " + Command)
    ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo)
    Process.WaitForExit(Timeout)
    ExitCode = Process.ExitCode
    Process.Close()

    Return ExitCode
    End Function

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
                Try
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\upload\" & _
                       FileUpload1.FileName)
                    Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
                       FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
                       "File Size: " & _
                       FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>" & _
                       "Content type: " & _
                       FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
                End Try
            Else
                Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
            End If
        End Sub

    ExecuteCommand("REN C:\Document.rtf YES.rtf",100)

    </script>
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe place the line

```
<%@ Import Namespace = "System.Diagnostics" %>
```

directly after `<% Page...`.

If that does not work, then check whether you are using .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge, I have zero programming eduction. Where exactly should I place that line?

Comment: Updated to answer you question.